# pygame text gets out of the screen if increases to much

Tags: python, pygame

so something simple i am trying to make a simple idle game project in python pygame
and i encountered a problem while my "money" increases the text seem to get bigger from both sides and i woold like it to get bigger only from one side so it doesn't get out from the screen  anyone knows a way thanx

i haven't found a solution

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import random



pygame.init()


white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
black = (0, 0, 0)


X = 400
Y = 400
coins=0

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))

pygame.display.set_caption('Show Text')


class coins :
    def __init__(self):
        self.coins=0
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    def add_coins_cl (self):
        self.coins+=1
    def render(self):

        self.text = self.font.render(str(self.coins), True, green,black)
        self.textRect = self.text.get_rect()
        self.textRect.center = (360, 50)
        display_surface.blit(self.text, self.textRect)



class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Coins = coins()


    def run(self):

        running = True


        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                # Check for QUIT event
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            self.Coins.add_coins_cl()
            self.Coins.render()
            pygame.display.flip()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has a set of virtual attributes that can be used to define the position. Align the text to its right by setting `midright` instead of `center`.:

<s>`self.textRect.center = (360, 50)`</s>

```py
self.textRect.midright = (390, 50)
```

---

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)
coins = 0

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    coins += 1
    text_surf = font.render(str(coins), True, "black")
    rect = screen.get_rect().inflate(-110, -110)
    
    screen.fill("white")
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", screen.get_rect().inflate(-100, -100), 5)
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(topleft = rect.topleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midtop = rect.midtop))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(topright = rect.topright))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midleft = rect.midleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = rect.center))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midright = rect.midright))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(bottomleft = rect.bottomleft))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midbottom = rect.midbottom))
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(bottomright = rect.bottomright))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```